# Prove $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$ are Lebesgue Measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I want to do this using Cartheodory's definition of a Lebesgue Measurable set which states:

A set $E$ is said to be measurable provided for any set $A$,
$$m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap E)+m^*(A\cap E^c) $$

For $\mathbb{R}$, I let $A$ be any set. Then by subadditivity of outer measure, we trivially have that:
$$m^*(A)\leq m^*(A\cap \mathbb{R})+m^*(A\cap \mathbb{R}^c) $$
since $A=(A\cap\mathbb{R})\cup(A\cap\mathbb{R}^c)$.

But by monotonicity of outer measure, we also know that:
$$A \cap \mathbb{R}\subset A \implies m^*(A \cap \mathbb{R})\leq m^*(A) $$
Therefore, we have
$$m^*(A) \geq m^*(A\cap\mathbb{R})= m^*(A\cap\mathbb{R})+0= m^*(A\cap\mathbb{R}) +m^*(A\cap\mathbb{R}^c) $$
since $m^*(A\cap\mathbb{R}^c)=m^*(\emptyset)=0$. Thus, since both are less than or equal to each other we must have that
$$ m^*(A)=m^*(A\cap \mathbb{R})+m^*(A\cap \mathbb{R}^c) $$

Measurability, by definition, is clearly symmetric so $\mathbb{R}$ measurable implies $\emptyset$ measurable.

Is this a complete proof? Do I need to show that the outer measure of $\emptyset$ is actually 0?

Comment: This proof is correct. As for showing $m^{*}(\emptyset) = 0$, what definition of the outer measure are you using?

Comment: That it's the infimum of the length of all open covers - but what covers the empty set?

Comment: Absolutely anything covers the empty set - remember $\emptyset \subseteq A$ for any set $A$.  In particular, any collection of open sets forms an open cover of $\emptyset$.